# how to redirect the page after checking the boolean value from database

Tags: cakephp

I am developing a hrm panel in cakephp. I want when employee punchin the page redirect to punchout page,but if employee logout the panel then he goes to punchin page that page must not be redirected until it checks the boolean value from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other answer because it does not show the best way to do it in CakePHP. If you use the router the code provided by the other answer will not work with routing. Also if your app is not in the root of the domain / but for example.com/my-tool/ the string type URL won't work either and the link is wrong, it would go to example.com/punchout instead of example.com/my-tool/punchout

```
if ($value === true) {
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'punchout'));
}
```

This is the correct way to do links in CakePHP for *all* links that point to any controller of your application. The string should be only used if it is an external URL. If you use links in your layout and have plugins and routing prefixes you also want to add the plugin and prefix key to the array and set it according to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Might it be so simple just to put your redirect code into a  IF statement?

```
if($boolean  === true) {
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'punchout'));
}
//normal code here when boolean is false
```

Comment: either `if ($value === true)` or just `if ($value)`

Comment: Downvoted because the string here will break the app in two cases (routing and if app is not in the root of the domain)

Comment: rather wish you would comment first and just let me edit my part, its hard enough to gain some rep when starting on this site.